# Android ServiceManager Waiting for service media.audio_flinger

Tags: android, android-videoview, servicemanager

I am working on an application that uses a video view to show a video. The video plays fine but for some reason on my G2 I am having an issue where after I close the app it will crash if I start it again. My Log is getting flooded with these calls:

These two stop if I manually force close my app.

```
INFO/ServiceManager(9007): Waiting for sevice media.player...

WARN/IMediaDeathNotifier(9007): Media player service not published, waiting...
```

These two just keep flooding in. I can't seem to find a way to get them to stop actually, short of restarting my device. The top one is appearing more often, at a rate of 5 to 1.

```
INFO/ServiceManager(1302): Waiting for sevice media.audio_flinger...

WARN/AudioSystem(1302): AudioFlinger not published, waiting...
```

Does anyone have any clue as to what might cause this behavior? Is there some sort of resources associated to VideoView that I should be releasing?

This same app works just fine and does not do this on my Galaxy Tablet.

Edit: This is actually causing any app that tries to use play media to timeout forceclose including the stock android Music app.

Comment: have you got anSWER? i am facing same problem?

Comment: Unfortunately I never got it figured out. At the time the specific application that I was working on was targeting a different device, and it worked correctly on that device. So I never had a chance to figure out what was going on with the G2. Is that the device that you are on?

Comment: i am targeting omap4 based devices...

Comment: This issue may have the same solution as [this question][question]. [question]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26375690/waiting-for-service-media-audio-policy-on-android-boot/43183347#43183347