# Waiting for service media.audio_policy on android boot

Tags: android

i am developing cyanogenmod 11 for my device samsung sm-g7102 garnd2
but it does not boot and gives bootloop on cyanogenmod logo.
the logcat shows following

#

```
W/AudioSystem( 684): AudioPolicyService not published, waiting...
I/ServiceManager( 684): Waiting for service media.audio_policy...
I/ServiceManager( 684): Waiting for service media.audio_policy...
I/ServiceManager( 684): Waiting for service media.audio_policy...
I/ServiceManager( 684): Waiting for service media.audio_policy...
I/ServiceManager( 684): Waiting for service media.audio_policy...
W/AudioSystem( 684): AudioPolicyService not published, waiting...
I/ServiceManager( 684): Waiting for service media.audio_policy...
I/ServiceManager( 684): Waiting for service media.audio_policy...
```

#

this goes on and on....

also if i delete libsecnativefeature.so from system/lib
it boots fine but there is no sound, camera, ril.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please edit the question and add the minimum code that is required to understand the problem. For more information read this article: [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

A Samsung Galaxy J5 I came around recently had a similar (if not same) problem and was stuck in a bootloop. Doing a quick search online, it seems this "**bootloop caused by audio error**" is common in many Samsung models, but not much information on it is out there.

The errors which were looping (obtained from **logcat**) included:

```
I/ServiceManager(  248): service 'media.audio_flinger' died
I/ServiceManager(  248): service 'media.player' died
I/ServiceManager(  248): service 'media.camera' died
I/ServiceManager(  513): Waiting for service media.audio_policy...
E/SamsungPowerSound(  513): wait_for_audio_policy
E/SamsungPowerSound(  513): media.audio_policy not published, waiting...
```

I was able to resolve the problem by **chmod**ing the file **/system/lib/libaudioflinger.so** to **755 (rwx-rx-rx)**. By default, the permissions were **644 (rw-r-r)**.

Since this solved the issue, my speculation is that a process with low privileges needed to execute the library file.

**Note:** I had to root the phone before I could edit the the permissions of the file. This voids the warranty. Also for most Samsung models, make sure you have enabled **OEM Unlock** else you risk wiping your phone via some flashing methods like **Odin**.

Comment: Did not work for me. And I don't believe this is the correct solution since all libs are 644.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I was beginning to doubt it myself. But was your problem also caused by audioflinger failing?

Comment: We had a problem with our build delaying the boot and random stalling for several minutes. As it turned out this was caused by wrong camera driver. Looks like audio_policy wasn't the cause. Haven't seen the error message recently. So to be honest, I don't even know if this message is serious. I removed the libaudioflinger (?) which made the device not boot any more. So somehow it seems to be working...

Comment: That's interesting. I do not have that phone with me anymore so I can't confirm. Maybe in the future someone will confirm if it is from the camera driver in their case as well. I will delete my answer if it turns out that that's the case. Thanks again for your feedback.